# KVM Debian - Disabling ICMP Redirect Acceptance makes SSH and ping impossible

Tags: ssh, debian, ping, kvm, icmp

I am currently setting up a VPN LT2P/IPSec on my Debian KVM following this tutorial :
http://bailey.st/blog/2011/07/06/secure-ipsecl2tp-vpn-for-on-the-road-android-devices/

Issuing this command :

`root@localhost:~# ipsec verify`

I got the following output

```
Checking your system to see if IPsec got installed and started correctly:
Version check and ipsec on-path                             [OK]
Linux Openswan U2.6.28/K2.6.32-5-686 (netkey)
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                            [OK]
NETKEY detected, testing for disabled ICMP send_redirects   [FAILED]

  Please disable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/send_redirects
  or NETKEY will cause the sending of bogus ICMP redirects!

NETKEY detected, testing for disabled ICMP accept_redirects [FAILED]

  Please disable /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/accept_redirects
  or NETKEY will accept bogus ICMP redirects!

Checking that pluto is running                                  [OK]
Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                              [FAILED]
  Cannot execute command "lsof -i UDP:500": No such file or directory
Pluto listening for NAT-T on udp 4500                       [FAILED]
  Cannot execute command "lsof -i UDP:4500": No such file or directory
Checking for 'ip' command                                   [OK]
Checking for 'iptables' command                             [OK]
Opportunistic Encryption Support                                [DISABLED]
```

So I edited this setting in /etc/sysctl.conf to

#### Disable ICMP Redirect Acceptance

`net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0`

I then restarted networking in /etc/init.d

Now my problem comes : I cannot connect through SSH to my KVM anymore nor ping the ip. (The only thing I can use is VNC)

How could I connect via SSH again without enabling the  ICMP Redirect Acceptance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the soluton  from github gist:
https://gist.github.com/kryptek/7683862

Comment: Downvoted. As the [relevant help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) says, "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 1):

If you just did `/etc/init.d/networking restart`  make sure that your interfaces are up (e.g. with `ifconfig`).  When I restarted networking like that on Debian wheezy it says:

> Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may
>   not re-enable some interfaces ... (warning)

And in fact I did discover that I needed to `ifup eth0` (rebooting should also work).

I don't think your problem has anything to do with ICMP redirect.  I disabled it on my KVM instance running wheezy and it accepts ping and ssh.  If it isn't the above issue then I would suspect something in your IPsec configuration is wrong and breaking netfilter.